# Ubuntu 20.04 brightness problem

Tags: grub2, 20.04, brightness, desktop-environments, lts

I have upgraded my system to Ubuntu 20.04 and am facing brightness issues. The brightness slider is also not showing up. Tried fixes such as brightness controller, made changes to gedit admin:///etc/default/grub (changed acpi backlight to vendor - no fix, changed to video - no fix). Also created file in /use/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf and changed it. No fix. Please provide any solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have just installed 20.04 on my Thinkpad AMD with Radion Vega graphics and I tried changing grub options and it didnt work.
Downloading drivers from AMD solved problem (after few restarts)

Resources I used:

- [Radeon™ Software for Linux® 20.30 Release Notes](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-20-30)
- [How to install](https://amdgpu-install.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install-script.html)

Hope this helps, if not for you then perhaps to someone else with AMD chipsets.

Comment: How did the reporting bugs page help you? Could you elaborate?

Comment: Sorry, edited to the correct link as how to install drivers